# build assembler file using makefile with iar compiler

Tags: c, assembly, makefile, iar

All the C code builds and links without error.
My assembly file is cstartup.s
I now need it to build the assembly file as well

In the makefile (cutdown a lot here, but remember it builds C code fine) I have this:

```
PROJ_SRC =  $(SRC_DIR)/plsi2c_riscv.c \
                    …
              $(SRC_DIR)/cstartup.s \


OBJ_FILES = $(addprefix $(BUILD_FOLDER)/,$(PROJ_SRC:.c=.o))
OBJ_FILES += $(addprefix $(BUILD_FOLDER)/,$(PROJ_SRC:.s=.o))

#compile C code
$(BUILD_FOLDER)/%.o: %.c
       #Create the folder structure for the output file
       @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
       $(RISCV_IARCC) $(RISCV_CFLAGS) $< -o $@

#compile .s code
$(BUILD_FOLDER)/%.o: %.s
       $(RISCV_IARCC) $(RISCV_CFLAGS) $< -o $@


#link
CC = $(RISCV_IARLINK)
$(BUILD_FOLDER)/twowire: $(OBJ_FILES)
       mkdir -p $(dir $@)
       @echo Linking $(notdir $@)
       $(CC) $(RISCV_LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS)
```

I always get this error:
make: *** No rule to make target '/c/BitBucket/riscv/src/release//c/BitBucket/riscv/src/cstartup.s'
Although cstartup.s is definitely in c/BitBucket/riscv/src (it is there with the file plsi2c_riscv.c)

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: You haven't given us a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but that double-slash catches my eye. What is the full path of `cstartup.s`?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to put the assembly code file string in another group eg PROJ_ASM

```
PROJ_SRC = $(SRC_DIR)/plsi2c_riscv.c \
                    …etc
PROJ_ASM = $(SRC_DIR)/cstartup.s \


OBJ_FILES = $(addprefix $(BUILD_FOLDER)/,$(PROJ_SRC:.c=.o))
OBJ_FILES += $(addprefix $(BUILD_FOLDER)/,$(PROJ_ASM:.s=.o))

#compile C code
$(BUILD_FOLDER)/%.o: %.c
       #Create the folder structure for the output file
       @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
       $(RISCV_IARCC) $(RISCV_CFLAGS) $< -o $@

#compile .s code
$(BUILD_FOLDER)/%.o: %.s
       $(RISCV_IARASM) $(RISCV_ASMFLAGS) $< -o $@


#link
CC = $(RISCV_IARLINK)
$(BUILD_FOLDER)/twowire: $(OBJ_FILES)
       mkdir -p $(dir $@)
       @echo Linking $(notdir $@)
       $(CC) $(RISCV_LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS)
```